# Holding mails back until post is out of review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, email

Could mails for followed tags be delayed when a post is still in a review queue?

I have my mails set up for every 15 minutes, because I want fast mails, but sometimes it happens that I get a mail for something completely unrelated, because a new user put the wrong tags in and it wasn't spotted fast enough, because nobody looked at the review queues so far.

It can also happen that someone gets spam in their mailbox because it wasn't picked up by the review people fast enough.

My suggestion for that is to delay the mail for 15 minutes if the post wasn't reviewed yet (no matter if you set your mail setting to every 15 minutes or every day, because you won't want to get a notification two days late, but rather a day and 15 minutes).

This change would especially be good for small sites, where it can often happen that nobody looks at the review queues, but less for big sites where the reason why nobody looked at it yet is because there are 10000 review items before it.
There should probably be a timeout to it, like after an hour or so the mail gets sent anyway.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe a CM can run a query to see how often this happens, that is: e-mail send while post in a review queue. And just to be clear, you want this to apply for all queues? So, suggested edit, close, re-open, low-quality, triage etc.

Comment: I don't know what "triage" is, but likely yes. It could also be dependent on the current review queue size, maybe only if less than 100 items are in it.

Comment: triage is a queue on SO, where new questions go in that meet certain low quality criteria.Yeah, review queue size could be factor, as might average time an item takes to leave the queue, things like that. I think we need some statistic data to see how much this will impact.